# htaccess 301 (permanent) redirection

Tags: .htaccess

I need help in 301 permanent URL redirection of dynamic URL's

`https://www.xyz.co/certificate.php?certify=iso-haccp`
should redirect to
 `https://www.xyz.co/certificate/iso-haccp-certification`

I want to do it using .htaccess file because there are so many url's like this, help me guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^certify=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^certificate\.php$ /certificate/%1-certification? [R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas, I made a little mistake in the question. I want to redirect https://www.xyz.co/certificate.php?certify=iso-haccp to https://www.xyz.co/certificate/iso-haccp-certification
and there are several values passed in "certify" parameter i.e. certify=haccp and certify=iso

Comment: hi, is this correct? RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^certify=$1
RewriteRule ^certificate\.php$ /certificate/$1-certification [R=301]

Comment: Hi. No your code is not correct. I edited my answer and put in the right code.

Comment: Hi Lucas, i tried your code to redirect https://www.xyz.co/certificate.php?certify=iso-haccp and resulting url is https://www.xyz.co/certificate/iso-haccp-certification?certify=iso-haccp  ...there is an additional part "?certify=iso-haccp" at the end of url...How to remove this

Answer (score 1):

A literal redirection would look like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} certify=(iso-haccp)
RewriteRule (certificate)\.php /$1/%1-certification? [R=301,L]
```

We're not using `^` or `$` in this example around the query string because it can allow for other variables that could be passed. I'm adding a `?` to the end of the redirection string to stop the default behavior of query string append.